# Oracle Reports Builder Barcode fonts disappearing

Tags: oracle, fonts, truetype, oraclereports

I have an issue with Oracle Reports builder. I am converting the RDF to XML and a few certain fonts, such as Barcode fonts disappear.
They are written in the XML though.

The images below show the result (F_4 even has a custom font and it works fine):

[image: Image of the two compared reports]

I've done some research into it myself and I haven't really been able to figure out the rule, why these fonts disappear or why they can be saved by report builder, but not reused from xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually managed to figure this one out. This issue was resolved in version 12.

In version 11, it appears that some fonts can bug out due to their charset configuration. Editing the font with a tool called FontForge, and assigning it the same value charset of the other fonts that worked, is what resolved it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed similar behavior. Though, I didn't use XML.

Reports Builder is probably the worst Oracle's product I've worked with. Unstable, crashes often, uses proportional fonts (where un-proportional would fit better; OK, that's not *bug*, that's just what I dislike), reports saved as .RDF can't be opened any more (for no reason, from my point of view) ...

Due to my last objection, I saved reports as .JSP and .RDF files (and exported it into .REP which was then copied to IAS).

.JSP file which contained barcode font (that's `F_7` in your example, right?) simply *lost it* (the barcode font). I have no idea why. What did I do? Edited field's properties and re-applied the barcode font.

That's how I learnt that report should be opened as a .RDF file because - again no idea why - it didn't lose barcode font information.

Therefore, try it and see if it helps >> edit the .RDF file when you work with reports.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that, that it doesn't disappear using RDF. I am converting from RDF to XML so I can change a line in python. I have noticed that too, that fonts just stay when using RDF. Guess it embeds them somewhere...

Comment: I hope my answer below resolves your troubles.